# Drupal takes 2+ min to post an article

Tags: 7, database

- I am hosting a Drupal 7 Instant on Amazon Ec2 and have database on RDS.
- The site loads and works pretty fast. But admin side, when articles are posted its dead slow.

In the MySql Log I found error like this:

> 130912 11:57:39 [ERROR] /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld: Out of memory
>   (Needed 26843536 bytes) 130912 11:57:39 [ERROR]
>   /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 26843536 bytes)

Mysql Myconf

```
default_storage_engine  = innoDb
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size  =  52428800
innodb_io_capacity = 10000
innodb_open_files = 120
max_allowed_packet = 33554432
max_connections = 3000
max_heap_table_size = 134217728
query_cache_size = 2147483648
read_buffer_size = 52428800
slow_query_log = 1
tmp_table_size = 134217728 
binlog_cache_size  =  32768
innodb_buffer_pool_size  = {DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_io_capacity = 10000
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8388608
innodb_log_file_size  =  134217728
key_buffer_size      = 16777216
log_output  =  TABLE
max_binlog_size  =  134217728
read_rnd_buffer_size  =  524288
thread_stack =  262144
read_only = {TrueIfReplica}
```

I am having very good configuration for both Ec2 Server & RDS (MySql).

**Ec2 Server Spec**

```
m3.xlarge
15 GB Ram
4 Dual Core Processor
20 ECU
```

**Rds Server Spec**

```
M1.Medium.
HDD Size: 10GB
Memory : 4 GB
CPU : 2 Compute Unit`
```

Traffic to site is around 2000 visits per day. The content of site is pretty much articles and few youtube videos.

Comment: Do you have memcache,APC installed ?

Comment: Are you using Apache ? if yes then have u installed Apc or memcache ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Drupal 7 so slow?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow)

Comment: If you are not using any memory hungry modules interfering with content creation, it's purely database config issue. If you do, share with us. We can't even tell if it's usual config problem (probably is - see link above), or some error you can simply fix on Drupal side. Please show us queries that cause problems, and if this is issue not yet answered, we might be able to help.

Comment: We are running apache. The maximum hits per day is 2500 users. The content in the site is news with 1 or 2 images. Maximum concurrent users are 25 users. All are anonymous. The users don't have any slowness or whatsoever. The admin has. They can't even post a news. It takes forever(like 5min).We are not using memcache. But APC is there. But does memcache improve write performance?

Comment: This is highly unusual. I agree, it seems like database misconfiguration. You shouldn't need memcache for that kind of load. I wonder if the fast response for anonymous users is due to all the pages being cached. If you turn off "Cache pages for anonymous users" in `/admin/config/development/performance`, does the site slow to a crawl?